# How to fill a many2one field depending on the values of a many2many field in odoo

Tags: odoo-8

I have one many2one field and many2many field referring to a common model.

```
case = fields.Many2one('csm')
cases  = fields.Many2many('csm')
```

Using this many2many field i will select multiple cases. Depending on these cases, case field (many2one) should fill. That is, the records selected in the many2many fields only should be visible in many2one field. Is it possible to do like this?
If so how can i do that?

Comment: If u know the answer. please tell me

Comment: @Naveen. I am sorry, I wasn't able to find a solution for this one.

Comment: That's sad. Okay if I find the answer, i ll let you know.@AKHIL MATHEW